# bin/hadoop: line 133: C:Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop

Can someone help on this? I am trying to get hadoop 2.2.0 version and got error message
$ bin/hadoop version
    bin/hadoop: line 133: C:Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: No such file or directory
    bin/hadoop: line 133: exec: C:Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory

I am trying to install single instance hadoop on windows 7/64.

I did install Cygwin64 and hadoop on "c/+1/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0"

JAVA_HOME is 
    $ echo $JAVA_HOME
    c:Java/jdk1.7.0_45

Any idea will be more than welcome so feel free to fire up!

Comment: If you want to respond to Simplefish below don't edit their answer, just post post a comment to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C:Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" is neither a valid Windows path nor a valid cygwin path. So your JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly. Set it to the directory where you installed the JDK. Maybe you mean "/cydrive/c/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java". Using "where java" or "which java" might help a bit.

(opinion follows...)

In my experience trying to set up hadoop on windows using cygwin is a tough battle, and usually not worth the effort. When I have to develop on Windows machines I usually set up a virtual machine running Linux, and everything tends to go much smoother.